# When is a transition radiationless?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser

I am reading the english wiki article about [population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion), to understand the laser. However the authors described different energy level transitions of the atom. But not all transitions emit photons. So I am wondering what determines if a specific energy transitions will result in the emission of a photon or not? What field of physics deals with those kind of calculations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radiationless transitions occur when the timescale for radiative decay is much longer than that for de-excitation by interactions/collisions with other atoms and molecules.

What you need to look at is the physics of [forbidden transitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_mechanism). The rate at which spontaneous emission occurs is ordinarily proportional to the square of the "electric dipole matrix" elements between the final and initial states.
$$A_{ji}\propto \left[\int \psi_f (-er) \psi^{*}_i\ d^3r \right]^2$$

Transitions governed by magnetic dipole or electric quadrupole transitions occur much more slowly - by roughly a factor of $\sim l^2/\lambda^2$, where $l$ is the size of the atom or molecule.

However, for certain combinations of the initial and final states, the electric dipole matrix element is *exactly* zero; this is possible for symmetric potentials with eigenstates that have definite parities. These forbidden transitions are identified by the [electric dipole selection rules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule) and are unlikely to occur radiatively unless in a very rarefied environment, such that a slower magnetic dipole or electric quadrupole transition has time to occur before a collisional de-excitation. Ordinarily, a radiative transition is never seen and de-excitation occurs by collision.

Answer (score 4):

The energy of an excited state has to go somewhere, so it is either lost by emitting a photon or some other mechanism must transfer the energy away. The most common of these mechanisms is [collisional de-excitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collisional_excitation) (that Wikipedia article is for collisional excitation, but de-excitation is the same process in reverse). The difference in the energy of the two states ends up as kinetic energy of the molecules/atoms involved.

In a solid the energy can also be lost to lattice vibrations, i,e, heat, which is generally known as quenching.

If the excited atom/molecule is isolated the only mechanism available is to emit a photon, so whether a collisional de-excitation occurs depends on the collision frequency with other atoms/molecules and de-excitation probability per collision.

Answer (score -2):

The electron simply slides over from a low vibrational state of the excited electronics state to a high vibrational state of the electronic ground.